# How do I remove a repository from SourceTree without deleting the contents on disk?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I recently copied a Git repository from one source folder on my local machine to another destination folder. However, I don't want to delete the source folder on my disk. What I do want to do, however, is to remove the source repo from my list in SourceTree. When I try to delete the repository from my list of repositories in SourceTree, I get the following message:

> Confirm Remove
>
> Are you sure you want to remove the following nodes, and all of their children?

I've attached a ScreenShot to show the list that I'm referring to.
[image: SourceTree Delete Repo Dialog]

I'm confused about what this message means. To me, it sounds like it wants to remove my repo even from the origin server. I've tried Googling this message but to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see [from this issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-228), this only affects your local configuration, not the remote repo.
I don't know of any GUI which would simply delete a remote repo.

Answer (score 5):

Building on @VonC's answer, deleting the repo's nodes (by clicking "OK" in SourceTree's dialog window - shown above) from SourceTree doesn't remove the repo from your disk, unless you want it to. To do so, you have to manually click "Also Move To Trash" as shown below. To just delete the repo from SourceTree, you just click "Remove Bookmarks".

[image: Move to Trash?]